# how to handle element.all(locator).each(eachFunction) in chai as promised

Tags: cucumber, protractor, chai, chai-as-promised

I am using Protractor, Cucumber, and Chai-As-Promise
I try to test a search field, and verify the each search result contains the search input value.  My prototype works great when Chai and Chai-As-Promised are used.
Here is the test case:  user inputs "fruit", a list of items will be returned: Apple Fruit, Orange Fruit, Pear Fruit.
I have something like below:

// in object file
...

```
   searchResultField: {
    get: function () {
        return element.all(by.repeater('result in Fruit'))
    }
},
```

...

```
//  in step file
this.Then(/^display all search result$/, function(callback) {
    Page.searchResultField.each(function(element){
        element.getText().then(function(value) {
            expect(promise.fulfilled(value.indexOf('Fruit') >-1)).to.eventually.be.true.and.notify(callback);

        });
    });
});
```

"error_message": "ReferenceError: promise is not defined

1) Everything shows as [object object] in console log.
2) without chai as promised, the Each, and "toContain" or IndexOf work like a charm, and very straight forward.  With Chai and Chai-As-Promised, I am not able to get the Each method work, nor able to "loop" the Fruit list and "expect" each of item.  (Note: the "expect" is declared chai.expect.
This is different than the other similar posting:[How do I handle an array of promises using Protractor w/ chai-as-promised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27865536/how-do-i-handle-an-array-of-promises-using-protractor-w-chai-as-promised)

Because the other posting know how many items in the array, and has fixed value.  In my case, I won't know the number of entries in my array.

In addition, how can I convert a promised to a readable format: For example, I need to know the value of the

```
Page.searchResultField.count()
```

But I can only get the object value.